# Undefined control sequence when running siunitx

Tags: texstudio, siunitx

Good morning,
when I try to load the siunitx package, TeX Studio reports undefined control sequence and missing \begin{document}.

The error can be replicated by compiling this piece of code:

```
\documentclass[preprint, 5p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    Test
\end{document}
```

I attach the whole log produced by the compiler

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.4.7)  24 APR 2019 18:20
entering extended mode
**./prova.tex
(prova.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 1
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.

(C:\Users\Alessandro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\elsarticle\elsarticle
.cls
Document Class: elsarticle 2009/09/17, 1.2.0: Elsevier Ltd
\@bls=\dimen102
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen103
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2016/10/09 v1.0u Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2017/01/12 v0.06k Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen104
\Gin@req@width=\dimen105
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\pifont.sty"
Package: pifont 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Pi font support (SPQR) 
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+pzd on input line 63.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\upzd.fd"
File: upzd.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for U/pzd.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+psy on input line 64.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\upsy.fd"
File: upsy.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for U/psy.
))
\c@tnote=\count88
\c@fnote=\count89
\c@cnote=\count90
\c@ead=\count91
\c@author=\count92
\@eadauthor=\toks15
\c@affn=\count93
\absbox=\box26
\keybox=\box27
\Columnwidth=\dimen106
\space@left=\dimen107
\els@boxa=\box28
\els@boxb=\box29
\leftMargin=\dimen108
\@enLab=\toks16
\@sep=\skip43
\@@sep=\skip44

(C:\Users\Alessandro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\natbib\natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip45
\bibsep=\skip46
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count94
)
\splwrite=\write3
\openout3 = `prova.spl'.


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count95
\Gm@cntv=\count96
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count97
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen110
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen111
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen112
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen113
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen114
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen115
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen116
\Gm@dimlist=\toks17

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fleqn.clo"
File: fleqn.clo 2016/12/29 v1.2a Standard LaTeX option (flush left equations)
\mathindent=\dimen117
Applying: [2015/01/01] Make \[ robust on input line 50.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 51.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Make \[ robust on input line 62.
Applying: [2015/01/01] Make \] robust on input line 74.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 75.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Make \] robust on input line 83.
))
(C:\Users\Alessandro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\siunitx\siunitx.sty
(C:\Users\Alessandro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2017/09/18 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\Alessandro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.t
ex
Package: expl3 2017/09/18 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count98
\l_tmpa_int=\count99
\l_tmpb_int=\count100
\g_tmpa_int=\count101
\g_tmpb_int=\count102
\g__intarray_font_int=\count103
\g__prg_map_int=\count104
\c_log_iow=\count105
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count106
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count107
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count108
\l__iow_indent_int=\count109
\c_zero_dim=\dimen118
\c_max_dim=\dimen119
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen120
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen121
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen122
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen123
\c_zero_skip=\skip47
\c_max_skip=\skip48
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip49
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip50
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip51
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip52
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count110
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count111
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count112
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count113
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count114
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count115
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count116
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count117
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count118
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count119
\c__fp_rand_size_int=\count120
\c__fp_rand_four_int=\count121
\c__fp_rand_eight_int=\count122
\l__sort_length_int=\count123
\l__sort_min_int=\count124
\l__sort_top_int=\count125
\l__sort_max_int=\count126
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count127
\l__sort_block_int=\count128
\l__sort_begin_int=\count129
\l__sort_end_int=\count130
\l__sort_A_int=\count131
\l__sort_B_int=\count132
\l__sort_C_int=\count133
\l__tl_build_start_index_int=\count134
\l__tl_build_index_int=\count135
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count136
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count137
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count138
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count139
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count140
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count141
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count142
\l__regex_balance_int=\count143
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count144
\l__regex_mode_int=\count145
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count146
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count147
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count148
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count149
\c__regex_catcode_D_int=\count150
\c__regex_catcode_S_int=\count151
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count152
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count153
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count154
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count155
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count156
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count157
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count158
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count159
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count160
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count161
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count162
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count163
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count164
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count165
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count166
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count167
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count168
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count169
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count170
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count171
\l__regex_step_int=\count172
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count173
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count174
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count175
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count176
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count177
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count178
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count179
\g__debug_trace_regex_int=\count180
\c_empty_box=\box30
\l_tmpa_box=\box31
\l_tmpb_box=\box32
\g_tmpa_box=\box33
\g_tmpb_box=\box34
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen124
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen125
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen126
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen127
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen128
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen129
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen130
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen131
\l__box_internal_box=\box35
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box36
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen133
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen134
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen135
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen136
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen137
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen138
\c_empty_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box39
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box40
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box41
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box42
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box43
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box44
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen139
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen140
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen141
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen142
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen143
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen144
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen145
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen146
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen147
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen148
)
(C:\Users\Alessandro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3pdfmode.de
f
File: l3pdfmode.def 2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
\l__driver_color_stack_int=\count181
\l__driver_tmp_box=\box45
))
(C:\Users\Alessandro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xpa
rse.sty
Package: xparse 2017/09/18 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count182
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count183
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count184
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count185
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count186
)
Package: siunitx 2018/05/17 v2.7s A comprehensive (SI) units package
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen149
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\array.sty"
Package: array 2016/10/06 v2.4d Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen150
\extrarowheight=\dimen151
\NC@list=\toks19
\extratabsurround=\skip53
\backup@length=\skip54
)
(C:\Users\Alessandro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\l3keys2e\l
3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2017/09/18 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
\l__siunitx_tmp_box=\box46
\l__siunitx_tmp_dim=\dimen152
\l__siunitx_tmp_int=\count187

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \seq_const_from_clist:Nn 
                                    \c__siunitx_old_options_seq {addsign,all...
l.258   }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...list:Nn \c__siunitx_old_options_seq 
                                                  {addsign,allowlitunits,all...
l.258   }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.258   }

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

\l__siunitx_number_mantissa_length_int=\count188
\l__siunitx_number_uncert_length_int=\count189
\l__siunitx_round_int=\count190
\l__siunitx_process_decimal_int=\count191
\l__siunitx_process_uncertainty_int=\count192
\l__siunitx_process_fixed_int=\count193
\l__siunitx_process_integer_min_int=\count194
\l__siunitx_process_precision_int=\count195
\l__siunitx_group_min_int=\count196
\l__siunitx_angle_marker_box=\box47
\l__siunitx_angle_unit_box=\box48
\l__siunitx_angle_marker_dim=\dimen153
\l__siunitx_angle_unit_dim=\dimen154
\l__siunitx_unit_int=\count197
\l__siunitx_unit_denominator_int=\count198
\l__siunitx_unit_numerator_int=\count199
\l__siunitx_unit_prefix_int=\count266
\l__siunitx_unit_prefix_base_int=\count267
\l__siunitx_unit_prefix_gram_int=\count268
\l__siunitx_number_product_int=\count269
\c__siunitx_one_fill_skip=\skip55
\l__siunitx_table_unit_align_skip=\skip56
\l__siunitx_table_exponent_dim=\dimen155
\l__siunitx_table_integer_dim=\dimen156
\l__siunitx_table_mantissa_dim=\dimen157
\l__siunitx_table_marker_dim=\dimen158
\l__siunitx_table_result_dim=\dimen159
\l__siunitx_table_uncert_dim=\dimen160
\l__siunitx_table_fill_pre_dim=\dimen161
\l__siunitx_table_fill_post_dim=\dimen162
\l__siunitx_table_fill_mid_dim=\dimen163
\l__siunitx_table_pre_box=\box49
\l__siunitx_table_post_box=\box50
\l__siunitx_table_mantissa_box=\box51
\l__siunitx_table_result_box=\box52
\l__siunitx_table_number_align_skip=\skip57
\l__siunitx_table_text_align_skip=\skip58
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareBinaryPrefix with sig. 'mmm' on line 7237.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIPostPower with sig. 'mm' on line 7240.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIPrefix with sig. 'mmm' on line 7243.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIPrePower with sig. 'mm' on line 7246.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIQualifier with sig. 'mm' on line 7249.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIUnit with sig. 'O{}mm' on line 7252.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIUnitWithOptions with sig. 'mmm' on line 7255.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \ang with sig. 'o>{\SplitArgument {2}{;}}m' on line 7270.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \num with sig. 'om' on line 7279.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \numlist with sig. 'o>{\SplitList {;}}m' on line 7288.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \numrange with sig. 'omm' on line 7297.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SIlist with sig. 'o>{\SplitList {;}}mm' on line 7309.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SIrange with sig. 'ommm' on line 7321.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \qty with sig. 'omom' on line 7333.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \sisetup with sig. 'm' on line 7336.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \tablenum with sig. 'om' on line 7351.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \si with sig. 'om' on line 7363.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \numInBookmark with sig. 'om' on line 7410.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \numrangeInBookmark with sig. 'omm' on line 7412.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SIInBookmark with sig. 'omom' on line 7414.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SIlistInBookmark with sig. 'omm' on line 7416.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SIrangeInBookmark with sig. 'ommm' on line 7418.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \siInBookmark with sig. 'om' on line 7419.
.................................................
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1

(C:\Users\Alessandro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\translator\tra
nslator.sty
Overfull \hbox (6018.29338pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 258--11
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 addsign,allowlitunits,allowoptarg,allowzeroexp,alsoload,angfo
rmat,anglesep,astroang,closeerr,closrfrac,closerange,colour,colorall,colourall,
colorneg,colourneg,colourunits,colourunits,colorvalues,colourvalues,decimalsymb
ol,debug,detectdisplay,digitsep,dp,emulate,errspace,eVcorra,eVcorrb,expbase,exp
product,fixdp,fixsf,fraction,inlinebold,loctolang,log,load,mathOmega,mathcelsiu
s,mathdegree,mathminute,mathmu,mathringA,mathrm,mathsOmega,mathscelsius,mathsde
gree,mathsecond,mathsf,mathsminute,mathsmu,mathsringA,mathsrm,mathssecond,maths
sf,mathstt,mathtt,negcolor,negcolour,noload,numaddn,numcloseerr,numdecimal,numd
igits,numdiv,numexp,numgobble,numopenerr,numprod,numsign,obeyall,obeybold,obeyf
amily,obeymode,obeyitalic,openerr,openfrac,openrange,padangle,padnumber,per,pre
fixbase,prefixproduct,prefixsymbolic,prespace,redefsymbols,repeatunits,retainpl
us,seperr,sepfour,sf,sign,slash,stickyper,strictarc,tabalign,tabalignexp,tabaut
ofit,tabexpalign,tabformat,tabnumalign,tabparseonly,tabtextalign,textOmega,text
celsius,textdegree,textminute,textmode,textmu,textringA,textrm,textsecond,texts
f,texttt,tightpm,tophrase,trapamigerr,trapambigfrac,trapambigrange,unitcolor,un
itcolour,unitmathrm,unitmathsf,unitmathsrm,unitmathssf,unitmathstt,unitmathtt,u
nitmode,unitsep,unitspace,valuecolor,valuecolour,valuemathrm,valuemathsf,valuem
athsrm,valuemathssf,valuemathstt,valuemathtt,valuemode,valuesep,xspace 
 []

Package: translator 2010/06/12 ver 1.10

(C:\Users\Alessandro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\translator\tra
nslator-language-mappings.tex)))
No file prova.aux.
\openout1 = `prova.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
(C:\Users\Alessandro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count270
\scratchdimen=\dimen164
\scratchbox=\box53
\nofMPsegments=\count271
\nofMParguments=\count272
\everyMPshowfont=\toks20
\MPscratchCnt=\count273
\MPscratchDim=\dimen165
\MPnumerator=\count274
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count275
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks21
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* hratio: 1:1
* vratio: 1:1
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(37.75394pt, 522.0pt, 37.75394pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(81.52342pt, 682.0pt, 81.52342pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=522.0pt
* \textheight=682.0pt
* \oddsidemargin=-34.51605pt
* \evensidemargin=-34.51605pt
* \topmargin=-52.74657pt
* \headheight=50.0pt
* \headsep=12.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=18.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=18.0pt
* \skip\footins=24.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 12.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumntrue
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)


(C:\Users\Alessandro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\translator\dic
ts\translator-basic-dictionary\translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-basic-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(C:\Users\Alessandro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\siunitx\siunitx-abbre
viations.cfg
File: siunitx-abbreviations.cfg 2017/11/26 v2.7k siunitx: Abbreviated units
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 5.
 [1

{C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}

] (prova.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 12937 strings out of 493333
 269455 string characters out of 3139180
 293849 words of memory out of 3000000
 16401 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 532371 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 40i,4n,33p,10358b,275s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr1
0.pfb>
Output written on prova.pdf (1 page, 18166 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 10 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I am aware that a similar question has already been answered ([Package siunitx gives undefined control sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429746/package-siunitx-gives-undefined-control-sequence)) but it does seem to appear again in the new release of siunitx, when it was supposed to be caused by a wrong release (supposedly fixed).

Many thanks

Comment: It's the usual MiKTeX issue: please run update both in user and 'Admin' modes.

Comment: With recent MikTeX and used packages your example work fine! As suggested @JosephWright, please upgrade your LaTeX installation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I have no problem compiling, but the present version of MiKTeX in the log is version 7000. So I suppose you should update.

Comment: I was very dumb to don't think of something that obvious. Many thanks to everyone

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: a complete fresh install should solved the promlem as I have described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520061/102825).