# Undefined control sequence \ifluatex when using document class comjnl.cls

Tags: miktex2.9

I am trying to compile a LaTeX into PDF with TexStudio and MikTek 2.9 on my windows 10 PC:

```
\documentclass{comjnl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    x
\end{document}
```

but I systematically get an error at line 189 of `pdftexcmds.sty`:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.189 \ifluatex
```

In the logs, I also see:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 186, version
  `2019/11/07' of package iftex, but only version
  `2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
  and LuaTeX' is available.
```

I have just reinstalled MikTex from scratch. The installed `iftex` version has been packaged on 10/11/2019.

Is this a bug? How can I solve this?

**P.S.** This issue does not happen when I use document class `article` or when I don't use package `amsmath`.

Comment: your miktex is not up-to-date, you are either missing the new version of the iftex package or an older version is interfering. Check for updates as user and as admin, and also check for new, not installed packages in both modes.

Comment: it is a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515968/errors-with-the-iftex-package-in-combination-with-the-hyperref-package)

Comment: Out topic: but note that, hopefully `comjnl.cls` was not created based on `lualatex`, please take care...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Ulrike's comment, I had not performed updates as a user (but I had done it as an admin). Then, I had to install `iftex`, refresh the database via MikTex's console and the issue is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where adding any `\usepackage{<packageName>}` before the `\begin{document}` statement would lead to the above error. I tried installing `pdftexcmds` and `iftex` packages by

```
mpm --admin --install=<packageName>
```

in a terminal with admin privileges, but it didn't help.

What I ended up doing was to uninstall the MiKTeX I had installed via Chocolatey by `choco uninstall miktex` and then uninstall the second MiKTeX installation which was still in my `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex` for some reason!. then I deleted the `MiKTeX` folders in:

1. `C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming`
2. `C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local`

and then I reinstalled MiKTeX through chocolatey by

```
choco install MiKTeX
```

it seems that my MiKTeX installation was messed up and a complete uninstall and a fresh reinstallation solves the above weird error!